# redirect loop for www non www

Tags: .htaccess, loops, redirect, url-rewriting

I changed my site to a static IP so I could rectify a canonical issue with IP / www using htaccess.
Now my www / non www redirect is causing a loop error
Depending on what I add to the htaccess file I either get loop error or no redirect.

Here's what I have that doesn't loop, but doesn't work either

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^77\.232\.74\.23
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I want the IP and the non www to redirect to www

the htaccess file is working as I also have an index.php rewrite that works

Answer (score 0):

Use `[OR]` condition, since you want to redirect to `www` site whether accessing your site by IP address or by non-www address:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^77\.232\.74\.23$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion but...that creates a "problem loading page" error

Comment: Can you access your website using `www.mysite.com` address?

Comment: So you can access the site using both `www.mysite.com` and `mysite.com ` URLs?

Comment: Then I am bit confused. Using what URL are you getting "problem loading page" error?

Comment: Sorry my fault. I can access both www and non with my code, but when I add your code I can only access non www. Any www urls show "problem loading page" error

Comment: Actually my rule doesn't even execute for a www URL. So I suspect something else is the problem. Try this in a different browser and make sure both www and non-www are pointing to same IP and same DOCUMENT_ROOT

Comment: just checked the domains are pointing to ip. with my code they both are ok...with your code the www shows error (Status: Maximum (10) redirects followed)

Comment: First you need to understand with your code rule isn't even executing. You're getting `www` because of some PHP/CMS framework you're using. Also can you paste your full .htaccess in question.

Comment: my redirect code worked before I got the dedicated IP could it be a setting in Servage that I've misunderstood?

Comment: I am not sure since I don't lot of details about your setup. TO start with just move out this .htaccess and then try to see what works or what not. Make sure there is no .htaccess or mod_rewrite anywhere and test in a new browser.

Comment: My host Servage suggested I changed where I pointed the domains in dns. So I now have the non www. address pointing to the old cluster IP and the www. pointing to the IP above. Your code now works for the non www. to the www. but not the IP to www.

Comment: Just to iterate that is IP address of your host. Try providing both the IPs in 2 different conditions using `[OR]`